# apache2 mod_proxy deny not working

Tags: apache2, mod-proxy

I have ubuntu apache2, I have a module called proxy, in the proxy.conf is this : (I have replaced my ip with XXX)

When I do this, the proxy works great,but it seems to be wide open for anyone to use. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

thanks
Joel

```
 <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
   ProxyRequests On

    <Proxy *:8080>
            AddDefaultCharset off
            Order deny,allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
    </Proxy>

    ProxyVia On
</IfModule>
```